# How to run SpFx WebPart in SharePoint Online without running Gulp server in background?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am new to SpFx and I am playing with SpFx.

I am trying the example given [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package).

I am able to follow the steps and I am able to add the WebPart to my SharePoint Page. But after adding, I am facing following error:

[image]

I am very much new to this SpFx.

When I run the command,

```
gulp serve
```

then the WebPart is running fine.

I want to know that how I can deploy the SpFx WebPart to SharePoint Online so that it can be available without running `gulp serve` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you mean by running it without gulp would be to package and deploy the webpart to SharePoint.

For that, you can follow the below steps:

1) Once you are done with the your local development, we need to configure a CDN path where we can host our files.

Go to the `config > write-manifests.json` file.

Here, enter your CDN path. It should be a path that can be accessible by the end users. It could be Azure or SharePoint or any thing else.

Modify it as below (sample code) and save the file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
  "cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->"
}
```

2) Now, you need to generate the files to be deployed.

For that run the below command:

```
gulp bundle –-ship
```

After this is done, you will find the a `temp > deploy` folder inside your solution as below:

[image]

Once this is generated, upload all the files inside the deploy folder to your CDN or Site Assets (as in our case). This task can also automated using advanced gulp tasks.

3) Now, we will create `spapp` file to be uploaded to app catalog.

For that, run the below command:

```
gulp package-solution –-ship
```

This will generate an sppkg file inside `sharepoint` folder as below:

[image]

Upload it to the app catalog. SharePoint will show you a popup and ask you to trust the client-side solution to deploy.

Click Deploy.

After that, you can add it like you add an App in a SharePoint site.

Comment: the files inside the deploy folder. It will be mostly js and json files

Comment: Thanks @GautamSheth, this was the exactly I needed. It worked.

Comment: welcome ! happy to help :)